# How do I encode unseen data with category_encoders?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, category-encoders

How to encode **a test dataset which doesn't have the target column** for the model to predict with category_encoders

I trained a model `category_encoders`, the `X_test` splitted from train.csv worked fine.

train.csv has 33 columns, including the target column named Target_column
test.csv has 32 columns, it doesn't have a target column named Target_column

Let's say

```
target_train= train['Target_column']
```

Then I do

```py
ds_cols1 = train.columns
encoder = ce.TargetEncoder(cols= [x for x in ds_cols1])
target_encoding = np.array(target_train)
Tar_encoded_train = encoder.fit_transform(train, target_encoding)
# X_unseen = encoder.transform(test)
```

But when I tried to encode it with the same encoder, it says it's expecting 33 columns instead of 32 column

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to specify *not* to encode the target column like so:

```py
import category_encoders as ce
import pandas as pd


training_data = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
test_data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

X_train = training_data.drop("target_column", axis=1)
y_train = training_data["target_column"]

encoder = ce.TargetEncoder(cols=X_train.columns)
encoded_train = encoder.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)

encoded_test = encoder.transform(test_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`category_encoders`](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/category_encoders) package calls previously unseen data as "unknown data". Most encoders have a `handle_unknown` attribute, which let you choose between a number of standard actions in such a case:

- `error`. Returns an error.
- `return_nan`. Replaces with a missing value (typically, `numpy.NaN`).
- `value`. Replaces with a pre-defined value.

You appear to be struggling with the [`TargetEncoder`](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/targetencoder.html) class. Looking at the version 2.6.3 documentation, it should have `handle_unknown = "value"`, which means that previously unseen values get replaced with the sample mean (for each column). Strange that it doesn't work like that for you.

You could try updating your `category_encoders` package version to the latest, and then specifying the `handle_unknown` attribute.